# função para remover item(todo list) não funciona em Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

O ultimo método da index.js é o removeTodo() que coloquei uma diretiva no botão mas não funciona. obrigado!
index.html

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return{
      newTodo:'',
      idforTodo:3,
      todos:[
        {
          id:1,
          title:"escrever um livro",
          completed:false
        },
        {
          id:2,
          title:"Ler sobre Wordpress",
          completed:false
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    addTodo(){
      this.todos.push({
        id: this.idforTodo,
        title: this.newTodo,
        completed:false
      })
      this.newTodo="",
      this.idforTodo++
    },
    removeTodo(index){
      this.todos.slice(index,1)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2> Todo List</h2>
  <input type="text" v-model="newTodo" />
  <input type="button" value="todo!" @click="addTodo"/>
  <h2>Lista</h2>
<div class="list" v-for="(todo,index) in todos">
  {{todo.id}} - {{todo.title}}
  <input type="button" value="x"  @click="removeTodo(index)"/>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tente usar splice no lugar de slice

Answer (score 1):

Para isto é só trocar o método **slice** pelo método **[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)**. O método slice gera um outro array, exatamente com o resultado do cortes, ou seja, ele retornaria os `resultados excluídos da lista`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return{
      newTodo:'',
      idforTodo:3,
      todos:[
        {
          id:1,
          title:"escrever um livro",
          completed:false
        },
        {
          id:2,
          title:"Ler sobre Wordpress",
          completed:false
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    addTodo(){
      this.todos.push({
        id: this.idforTodo,
        title: this.newTodo,
        completed:false
      })
      this.newTodo="",
      this.idforTodo++
    },
    removeTodo(index){
      this.todos.splice(index,1)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2> Todo List</h2>
  <input type="text" v-model="newTodo" />
  <input type="button" value="todo!" @click="addTodo"/>
  <h2>Lista</h2>
<div class="list" v-for="(todo,index) in todos">
  {{todo.id}} - {{todo.title}}
  <input type="button" value="x"  @click="removeTodo(index)"/>


</div>
</div>
```